# partykit: justify text in terminal node when unequal regressors' name lengths are included

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, party

I am trying to edit the esthetics of the terminal node to:

1. Increase the size of the box such that the full names are listed inside of it.
2. If possible, justify the text inside when in the presence of unequal regressors' name lengths to produce a table-like view of the terminal nodes.

Below I listed my attempts, using the `gp` option `(fontsize = 10, boxwidth = 10)`, but I suspect that I am using the wrong esthetics options.

The `mysummary` function is highly inspired in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495322/partykit-modify-terminal-node-to-include-standard-deviation-and-significance-of/65500344#65500344).

```
library("partykit")

set.seed(1234L)
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes", package = "mlbench")
## a simple basic fitting function (of type 1) for a logistic regression
logit <- function(y, x, start = NULL, weights = NULL, offset = NULL, ...) {
                  glm(y ~ 0 + x, family = binomial, start = start, ...)}


## Long name regressors
PimaIndiansDiabetes$looooong_name_1 <- rnorm(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
PimaIndiansDiabetes$looooong_name_2 <- rnorm(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))
## Short name regressor
PimaIndiansDiabetes$short_name <- rnorm(nrow(PimaIndiansDiabetes))


## set up a logistic regression tree
pid_tree <- mob(diabetes ~ glucose        + 
                          looooong_name_1 +
                          looooong_name_2 +
                          short_name      | 
                          pregnant + pressure + triceps + insulin +
                          mass + pedigree + age, data = PimaIndiansDiabetes, fit = logit)

## Summary function from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65495322/partykit-modify-terminal-node-to-include-standard-deviation-and-significance-of/65500344#65500344
mysummary <- function(info, digits = 2) {
  n <- info$nobs
  na <- format(names(coef(info$object)))
  cf <- format(coef(info$object), digits = digits)
  se <- format(sqrt(diag(vcov(info$object))), digits = digits)
  t <- format(coef(info$object)/sqrt(diag(vcov(info$object))) ,digits = digits)

  c(paste("n =", n),
    paste("Regressor","beta" ,"[", "t-ratio" ,"]"),
    paste(na, cf, "[",t,"]")
  )
}

#plot tree
plot(pid_tree,
     terminal_panel = node_terminal,
     tp_args = list(FUN = mysummary,fill = c("white")),
     gp = gpar(fontsize = 10,
               boxwidth = 10,           ## aparently this option doesn't belonw here,
               margins = rep(0.01, 4))) ## neither this does.
```

This is what I am getting:
[image]

but I would like to get something like the following:

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple and basic solution is to use a proportional width font like Courier or Inconsolata:

```
plot(pid_tree, terminal_panel = node_terminal,
  tp_args = list(FUN = mysummary, fill = "white"),
  gp = gpar(fontfamily = "inconsolata"))
```

[image: tree with inconsolata text]

In addition to this simple text-based table, you can also produce more elaborate tables, e.g., via `ggplot2` and `gtable` as in the following plot taken from: Seibold, Hothorn, Zeileis (2019). "Generalised Linear Model Trees with Global Additive Effects." *Advances in Data Analysis and Classification*, **13**, 703-725. [doi:10.1007/s11634-018-0342-1](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11634-018-0342-1)

[image: palmtree with custom table]

The code is a little bit involved but available in the replication materials of the article. Specifically, you need these two files:

- [Supplementary material 1](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11634-018-0342-1/MediaObjects/11634_2018_342_MOESM1_ESM.r)
- [Supplementary material 10](https://static-content.springer.com/esm/art%3A10.1007%2Fs11634-018-0342-1/MediaObjects/11634_2018_342_MOESM10_ESM.r)

Comment: Wow, that's, as usual, a brilliant answer @AchimZeileis thank you so much for your time. I was wondering if there is a piece of documentation regarding **graphical parameters** (`gp`), that I am not aware of? After a quick search for `fontfamily` I got no hits in the official [`partykit` documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/partykit/partykit.pdf). Am I searching in the wrong place for such options? For example, I would also like to control the distance of the threshold values from the node (e.g., the number `<=26.3` from node `[1]` to `[2]`) and I couldn't find it. Thx again!

Comment: The `gpar` graphical parameters are from the general `grid` package, not specific to `partykit`, see `help("gpar", package = "grid")`. The distance of the edge labels from the nodes cannot be controlled, I think.